# Reaching the number 42 by recursion

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to create a bear game where the user enters a number (n), and the program will see if it can reach the number 42 by doing some specified steps. If it can't, then it notifies the user that number can't reach the goal.

**These are the rules:**

1. If n is even, then you may give back exactly n/2 bears.
2. If n is divisible by 3 or 4, then you may multiply the last two digits of n and give back this
   many bears.
3. If n is divisible by 5, then you may give back exactly 42 bears.

Here's an example:

- Start with 250 bears
- Since 250 is divisible by 5, you may return 42 of the bears, leaving you with 208 bears.
- Since 208 is even, you may return half of the bears, leaving you with 104 bears.
- Since 104 is even, you may return half of the bears, leaving you with 52 bears.
- Since 52 is divisible by 4, you may multiply the last two digits (resulting in 10) and return
  these 10 bears. This leaves you with 42 bears.
- You have reached the goal!

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool bears(int n);

int main(){
    int number;

    do{
        cout<<"enter the amount of bears (press 0 to stop the program): ";
        cin>>number;
        if (bears(number)){
            cout<<"you have reached the goal!"<<endl;
        }

        else{
            cout<<"sorry, you have not reached the goal."<<endl;
        }

    }while(number != 0);
}

bool bears(int n){
    if (n < 42){
        return false;
    }

    else if (n == 42){
        return true;
    }

    else{
        if (n % 5 == 0){
            return bears(n - 42);
        }

        else if(n % 2 == 0){
            return bears(n / 2);
        }

         else if(n % 4 == 0|| n % 3 == 0)
        {
            int one;
            int two;
            one=n%10;
            two=(n%100)/10;
            return bears(n - one * two);
        }  
    }
}
```

My program has the basic rules, but when I type in 250 bears it says it can't reach the goal. I understand what's happening in the code and why it can't reach the specified goal, but how do I make it universal so it'll work not just for the number 250, but for other numbers like: 84.

Comment: All the recursive calls need to be `return bears(...);`.

Comment: @Barmar My question is nothing like that question that you have pointed to. Also, returning does not fix the problem. The problem is the same even with the return statement added.

Comment: Read the question and you will know this is not an exact duplicate....

Comment: Step through the program in the debugger, that should pinpoint the problem.

Comment: That was definitely the problem in the code you originally posted. Now that you've edited it, I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @Barmar As I have stated in the question, I know what the problem is. I know why it's saying it can't reach the goal. What I am saying is how can I make it more versatile, so that it knows which rule to go to. For example, even though 52 is even, instead of going through the even else if statement, I divide by 4 instead.

Comment: Just change the order of the tests, so you check `if (n % 4 == 0)` before you check `if (n % 2 == 0)`

Comment: @Barmar But if I do that, then when it's 208, it's divisible by 4 so when you multiply 0 and 8, 0 bears are returned, causing an infinite loop. But I could skip that else if statement if the last two numbers are 0. If they are, I could go to the even else if statement and that should work

Comment: The mod 4 in your final else if statement is useless because any number that would be divisible by 4 would also be divisible by 2, therefore being caught in the previous condition

Comment: @user2896120 That seems like a problem with the  rules. It doesn't say what to do when multiple criteria match, like multiples of 10 fit both rule 1 and rule 2.

Comment: Like you already pointed out, the issue is that you are only considering the first matching rule instead of all of the fitting ones. To change that you can introduce a vector with all the possible number of bears after applying a fitting rule. Then you iterate over that vector doing the same. In the end you return true if you find at least one sequence leading to 42 bears.

Comment: This is potentially a complicated problem. You need an intelligent way of choosing the rules at each step. May be for a given number if you apply rule 1 in the first step, you go to a path that you can never get to 42, but if you start with rule 3 there is a path. I would suggest add the label algorithm to this and discuss it there. This is an algorithm design problem not a C++ or recursion question.

Comment: I added the label. It is pending peer review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Corristo's answer is good, but a similar depth first search algorithm can be used with minimal changes to your code. I've removed the redundant `if`s and `else`s (since we're returning in every condition).

What this function does is instead of using a greedy approach like your solution does, it tests *all* cases till it finds an answer. Your code tests the second condition only if the first condition (divisibility by 5) is *not* satisfied, and so on.

```
bool bears(int n){
    if (n < 42)
        return false;

    if (n == 42)
        return true;

    // Moves on if condition isn't satisfied
    if ((n % 5 == 0) && bears(n - 42)) return true;

    if ((n % 2 == 0) && bears(n / 2)) return true;

    if(n % 4 == 0|| n % 3 == 0)
    {
        int one;
        int two;
        one=n%10;
        two=(n%100)/10;
        return one * two != 0 && bears(n - one * two);
    }  

    return false;
}
```

You can try optimizing it further by using a cache (`std::map`) where you store the results and return the stored result if you have computed it before, but it'll only help in very few cases.

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't have any a priori knowledge about which rule we need to choose for a particular number, the easiest way is to try all of them by exploring the entire state space. You can think of it as a reachability problem in an implicitly given graph.

One way to solve such a reachability problem is by using breath-first or depth-first search, which can be implemented recursively.

For your game this can be done by modifying your `bears` function to take a `std::vector` of integers for which it checks if it contains at least one number from which 42 can be reached.

With a depth-first search it might look as follows:

```
bool bears(std::vector<int> ns) {
    // first remove all numbers < 42 since the goal cannot be reached from them
    ns.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(ns), std::end(ns),
                            [] (auto const& n) { return n < 42; }),
             std::end(ns));

    if (ns.empty()) {
        return false;
    } else  if (std::any_of(std::cbegin(ns),
                            std::cend(ns),
                            [] (auto const& n) { return n == 42; })) {
        return true;
    } else {
       auto possible_number_of_bears = std::vector<std::vector<int>>{};
       std::transform(std::cbegin(ns),
                      std::cend(ns),
                      std::back_inserter(possible_number_of_bears),
                      [] (auto const& n) {
                            auto after_possible_rules = std::vector<int>{};
                            if (n % 5 == 0) {
                                after_possible_rules.emplace_back(n - 42);
                            }

                            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                                after_possible_rules.emplace_back(n / 2);
                            }

                            if (n % 4 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
                                int one;
                                int two;
                                one = n % 10;
                                two = (n % 100) / 10;
                                // avoid infinite recursion by only adding
                                // the new number if it is different from n
                                if (one * two != 0) {
                                    after_possible_rules.emplace_back(n - one * two);
                                }
                            }
                            return after_possible_rules; });
        return std::any_of(std::cbegin(possible_number_of_bears),
                           std::cend(possible_number_of_bears),
                           bears);
    }
}
```

Now you only need to adjust the calling code to

```
 if (bears({number})) {
     std::cout << "you have reached the goal!" << std::endl;
 } else {
     std::cout << "sorry, you have not reached the goal." << std::endl;
 }
```

and modify the forward declaration of `bears` accordingly.

Comment: What's the reason for making `bears` take a vector? It seems to me that the code would be a *lot* simpler if it took a single number instead.

Comment: @interjay Maybe that is because I come from a functional programming background, but I tend to model non-determinism by using vectors. The only other alternative that comes to my mind is to implement a "real" DFS/BFS which would need a stack/queue,  I don't think that is much simpler. So if you have an implementation that takes a single number *and* is simpler in mind, please go ahead and post it as an answer.

Comment: If you think of the problem in terms of mathematical sets of reachable numbers, I think this is actually quite intuitive. You start with a set containing the single element the user provided, and then in each iteration a single number in the set of numbers you already found to be reachable gets mapped to the set of possible successors (hence you end up with a set of sets, or a vector of vectors). Since `std::vector` is superior to `std::set` performancewise in almost all cases I use `vector` when I didn't do additional measurements.

Comment: Using a vector to model non-determinism is fine, but it can be a lot simpler. Just have the function take a single `int` parameter, create your `after_possible_rules` vector based on it, and then call `std::any_of` on that. Adding an additional vector on top of that significantly complicates the code for no benefit, and makes it more difficult to add memoization.

Comment: @interjay If you do that you get a BFS instead of a DFS :) Having seen the solution of  EvilTak I agree that mine is overly complicated, but I'll leave it here as it is easily modifyable to search breadth-first which might be useful for other similar cases, e.g. if you also want to output a shortest certificate for the found solution.

Comment: It would still be a DFS. For a BFS you need a FIFO queue, so it can't be implemented recursively like DFS (of course you can implement a loop using tail recursion and pass in the queue as a parameter, but that's not really using the power of recursion like DFS).